# How to add some sort of button on github readme.md file?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I have questions about writing a readme.md file for Github.

When I looked around another repository, I found some sort of button or widget ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/880VB.png)) at readme.md file. I don't know what they are called or how to set them into my project.

How are they called and how to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're badges or shields. You can find them on sites like https://shields.io/category/build.

It's basically an image and a link.